# Testing SQL Procedure Exception Check

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

I created the below PL/SQL procedure on Oracle SQL Developer 11g, and would like to force test an exception to make sure the email that I coded into it actually does send out when an exception occurs. Can someone please let me know how I can do that?

```
create or replace
procedure Procedure_1 as
-- This script updates the 'owner_id' field on Schema.table1 to 'SYSADMIN' for FISCAL, BREAKDWN, and PROGRAM table types.
--

v_code          number;
v_errm          varchar2(512);
vOM_Recipients  VARCHAR2(200) := 'personal_email@email.com';

begin
update Schema.table1
set owner_id = 'SYSADMIN'
where table_type in ('FISCAL','BREAKDWN','PROGRAM') and owner_id <> 'SYSADMIN';
commit;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
     v_code := SQLCODE;
     v_errm := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1 , 512);
     UTL_MAIL.send(sender => 'automated_email@email.com',
                             recipients => vOM_Recipients,
                                   subject => 'Procedure_1 Job Error',
     message => 'Procedure_1 Job Error.' || chr(10) || chr(10) ||
     'The error code is '||v_code||'-'||v_errm||' ');
end;
```

Comment: Depends on what you have ability to do.  Can you temporarily add a "raise_application_error" call to the beginning of this procedure? Or revoke update on Schema.table1 from whatever user owns this procedure?  Or rename the table?  Or put a unique constraint on owner_id on the table?  Or change owner_id to a datatype incompatible with 'SYSADMIN'?

Comment: Craig, thanks for the reply. I am the owner of the procedure, and do have full control to update the procedure at will. What kind of "raise_application_error" line should I add to force the exception?

Comment: If you just want to throw a random error `raise_application_error(-20001, 'Some Random Message');`.

Comment: Thank you, Justin! This answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment from Justin Cave:
If you just want to throw a random error raise_application_error(-20001, 'Some Random Message');